# jquery : $().animate() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done quite a bit of searching and was not able to find an answer to my question, so here goes.

I am trying to create a slideout toggle menu with [this tutorial](http://alijafarian.com/jquery-horizontal-slideout-menu/), and I'm getting an error `slideoutMenu.animate is not a function`

here is the html div in question:

```
<div id="corner-button"><a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">myLink</a></div>

    <div class="slideout-menu">
            <h3><a href="#" class="slideout-toggle">Toggle</a></h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Add new task</li>
                <li>See completed tasks</li>
                <li>Go to metrics page</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and here is my js function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("in the toggle func");
            var slideoutMenu = $(".slideout-menu");
            var slideoutMenuWidth = $(".slideout-menu").width();
            console.log("width : " + slideoutMenuWidth);
            slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

            if(slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")){
                console.log("open....");
                slideoutMenu.animate({
                    left: "0px"
                }, 500);
            } else {
                slideoutMenu.animate({
                left: -slideoutWidth
                }, 250);
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried a number of things, wrapping the above within a straight javascript function and using

```
(function($){
    // code here
})
```

but they all result in the same error. The q's I found related to that issue here on stackoverflow mainly directed users to have 'animate' instead of 'animated' or to make sure they use a jquery obj and not a dom obj.

Browsed thru quite a few others, but they just variations on what I had already done. tested in firefox and chrome.

when adding a console log statement `console.log($.fn.jquery);` I get:

```
3.1.0 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector,-deprecated
```

thanks.

Comment: uhm... that doesn't make sense, given your code. the error that is. it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: html added, bad spacing before

Comment: what does `console.log($.fn.jquery)` give you?

Comment: What version jquery and jquery UI did you use? I think I recall having an issue with this with an incompatible jquery version...

Comment: it was the version. I added an older ver of jquery and that did the trick. Post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: well, the problem is you're using the slim version of jquery 3.1.0, you need the full version. the hint is in all the -ajax things in the version property. Those are all the things not included.

Comment: @KevinB should post his as the answer, as i was just guessing  =)

Comment: my bad re: slim ver, did not realize there was a difference

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You appear to be using the slim build of jQuery 3.1.0, which doesn't include most of the library. Instead, you should be using the full version.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js

Comment: latest version can always be found here https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/