# jQuery scroll to div onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm trying to implement a scroll to div on my website http://www.dicosoftware.com to have smooth scroll to each section of the site but it's not working.  You can go to the site to verify, and any feedback that can be provided will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the following jQuery functions under the main.js file.

```
 $(".js--scroll-to-main").click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#header").offset().top},2000);
 });

 $(".js--scroll-to-about_us").click(function({
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#sectionabout_us").offset().top},2000;
 });

 $(".js--scroll-to-services").click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#section-services").offset().top},2000);
 });

 $(".js--scroll-to-contact_us").click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#section-contact_us").offset().top},2000);
 });
```

My links are setup under an unordered list

```
<ul class="main-nav hidden js--main-nav">
    <li> <a class="js--scroll-to-main" href="#">Inicio</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="js--scroll-to-about_us" href="#">Nosotros</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="js--scroll-to-services" href="#">Servicios</a> </li>
    <li class="contact-link"> <a class="js--scroll-to-contact_us" href="#">Contactanos</a> </li>
</ul>
```

and each section is setup under the following divs.

```
 <header id="header"> ... </header>
 <section class="section-about_us js--section-about_us" id="section-about_us"> ... </section>
 <section class="section-services js--section-services" id="section-services"> ... </section>
 <section class="section-contact js--section-contact" id="section-contact_us"> ... </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the error in the console:

`TypeError: $('html, body').animate is not a function.`

In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647190/jquery-animate-is-not-a-function) it was pointed out that the slim build of jQuery does not include a lot of functionality.

You should change your script below to a full version of jQuery:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>`

such as:

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js`