# JavaScript Caroussel Not Sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I am new to Javascript and trying to get a slider to auto-slide. Problem is it doesn't slide. I cant even click it to make it slide. My code is as follows, (I have included a full page sample). The caroussel should slide div by div (one at a time) but nothing happens. IT actually feels as though my Javascript isn't even being executed at all.  any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    #myslide {
        width:705px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position: relative;
        height:80px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    #myslide .cover {
        width:2820px;
        position: absolute;
        height:80px;
    }

    #myslide .mystuff {
        width:705px;
        float:left;
        padding:20px 0;
        font-size:15px;
        font-style: italic;
        color:#b0b0b0;
        line-height:20px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .button1,
    .button2,
    .button3,
    .button4    {
        background:#999;
        padding:6px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin-right:5px;
    }

    .active { 
        background:#111;
        padding:6px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        outline:none;
    }
    .clear { clear: both; }

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="myslide">
  <div class="cover">
      <div class="mystuff">
          1 Lorem Dolor Ipsum...
      </div>
      <div class="mystuff">
          2 Lorem Dolor Ipsum...
      </div>
      <div class="mystuff">
          3 Lorem Dolor Ipsum...
      </div>
      <div class="mystuff">
          4 Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet ....
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="button">
  <a class="button1 active" rel="1"></a>
  <a class="button2" rel="2"></a>
  <a class="button3" rel="3"></a>
  <a class="button4" rel="4"></a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){

$('#button a').click(function(){
    var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-705*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
    $('#button a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
            $(this).addClass('active')}
    });
});
    Next();
    setInterval ( function(){Next();}, 1000 );
});

function Next(){
    var _next = false;
    $('#button a').each(function(){
        if(_next){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            _next = false;
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            _next = true;
            _next = true;
            $(this).removeClass('active')
        }

    });  
    if(_next)
        $("#button a:eq(0)").addClass("active");

   var activeIndex = parseInt($(".active").attr("rel"));
   $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-705*(parseInt(activeIndex)-1)});      
}


</script>
```

Comment: "IT actually feels as though my Javascript isn't even being executed at all" so why not add a couple of console statements and see.

Comment: For starters, your functions aren't closed correctly. You're missing curly braces after your `else if` statement. Secondly, you're using jQuery Slim, which doesn't include any animation functions. Instead, use the regular jQuery library.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie You were right the problem was jquery slim. Once i fixed the else if and changed libraries it all worked out thanx. Would you write up the answer so i can accept it. Give Credit where its due

Comment: @LawlessLeopard Done. Thanks. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your functions aren't closed correctly. You're missing curly braces after your else if statement. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$('#button a').click(function(){
    var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-705*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
    $('#button a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
            $(this).addClass('active')}
    });
});
    Next();
    setInterval ( function(){Next();}, 1000 );
});

function Next(){
    var _next = false;
    $('#button a').each(function(){
        if(_next){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            _next = false;
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            _next = true;
        }
    })
}
```

Secondly, you're using jQuery Slim, which doesn't include any animation functions (see [jquery : $().animate() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647190/jquery-animate-is-not-a-function)). Instead, use the regular jQuery library.