# Smooth scrolling on BS4 fixed navbar with scrollspy

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling

WARNING: I'm new to JavaScript.

I am developing a site for a family member and I've stumbled upon a problem. I am using Bootstrap 4 for the site, and therefor their navbar framework. The navbar is fixed to the top, and uses ScrollSpy to highlight the active section.

I am using this code from W3 to have my Nav links slowly scroll down the page to a section.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

No luck. My nav links nolonger work, and I get these nasty console errors

```
master.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (master.js:15)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

I know what you're thinking, master.js is sourced before jQuery. Nope!

I would appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer here: [jquery : $().animate() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647190/jquery-animate-is-not-a-function)

> You appear to be using the slim build of jQuery 3.2.1, which doesn't
>   include most of the library. Instead, you should be using the full
>   version.
>
> https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js

Comment: Hi Ryan. This makes my links work but has broken my ScrollSpy and they aren't smooth yet.

Comment: @SmocksMCM I would need to see your references to ScrollSpy to help there along with your markup on the nav. Which should be posted into a new question :)

Comment: Also, Ryan, I am now getting these nasty errors. `Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE='. The resource has been blocked.
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
master.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at master.js:1`

Comment: You need to remove the integrity and crossorigin properties from your source: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script> [rest of head]`. After doing this, I got the codepen to work along with the smooth animations.

Comment: Thansk! Works like a charm!

Comment: One more thing, the NavBar takes up some space at the top. How can I add a top offset to the scrolling so I see the entire section

Comment: @SmocksMCM `var scrollPixels = $(hash).offset().top - $('nav').height();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPixels
      }, 800, function(){

        window.location.hash = scrollPixels;`