# jQuery code doesn't work when link to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navbar, smooth-scrolling

I have been working with jquery for some of the baisc smooth scrolling functions in Codepen, everything seems works except for that navbar-shrink transition in codepen. So I deceided to try it in Visual Studio Code Editor and that's when things went wrong. It seems that my jquery code is no long working at all, even thought I checked file links in html and I think everything has been linked together and I did not change any of my code. Why my jquery code is not working at all. I started off withe bootstrap 4 starting template and what could I possible did wrong, can anyone take a look at my code and give me some feedback, appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scrollLink = $('.scroll');
    scrollLink.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 900)
    })

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

        if ($('.navbar').offset().top > 100) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-shrink');
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-shrink');
        }
        scrollLink.each(function () {
            var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            if (sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```css
section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 900px;
}

#home {
 background-color: lightblue;
}

#about {
 background-color: lightsalmon;
}

#contact {
 background-color: lightgray;
}

.active {
 background-color: blue !important;
 color: #FFF !important;
}

* {
 transition: all .4s ease-in 0s;
}

.navbar-shrink {
 
 height: 45px;
/*  background-color: transparent !important; */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top transition">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section id='home'>Home</section>
    <section id='about'>About</section>
    <section id='contact'>Contact</section>
   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src='main.js'>

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's not working? This example seems to be working as you described it should. The only console errors I see is the references to relatively linked resources on your server (_main.js_ and _style.css_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using slim version of jQuery without animate and many other functions.

Read here
[jquery : $().animate() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647190/jquery-animate-is-not-a-function)

This fixes problem:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js

Answer (score 1):

You should add these styles below:

```
.navbar-shrink {
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s linear;         
  transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
}

.navbar { 
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s ease; 
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s ease;        
  transition:padding 0.2s ease;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code and the animation works now. Really appreciated your help.